# Java ResultSet Column '<column_name>' not found

Tags: java, exception, resultset

I have a ResultSet I am pulling from a database that contains the column in question.  I know this because when I loop through the records, I also loop through the columns:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

try {

    while(rs.next()) {      

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();                          
        for (int i=1; i<numColumns+1; i++) {                    
            String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            System.out.println(Time.formatDate(System.currentTimeMillis(),  true)+" - [ResultSetConverter.convert] column_name ["+column_name+"]");

            ...

            // line where exception is thrown
            obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name)+"");

         }

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(Time.formatDate(System.currentTimeMillis(),  true)+" - [ResultSetConverter.convert] Exception: "+e.getMessage());            
}
```

In doing so, I am printing into the console the column names to verify existence:

```
4/1/2015 01:18 PM - [ResultSetConverter.convert] column_name [_id]
4/1/2015 01:18 PM - [ResultSetConverter.convert] column_name [image]
4/1/2015 01:18 PM - [ResultSetConverter.convert] column_name [company_code]
4/1/2015 01:18 PM - [ResultSetConverter.convert] Exception: Column 'company_code' not found.
```

As you can see, right after I print the column `company_code` the exception is encountered!

The data is from MySQL and the field definition is:

```
`company_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'company_code' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5729)
    at com.sequon.core.ResultSetConverter.convert(ResultSetConverter.java:96)
    at com.sequon.core.Database.getDevicesForMap(Database.java:1360)
    at com.sequon.api.Data.getDevices(Data.java:751)
    at com.sequon.api.Data.getData(Data.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: Can you post the rest of code where you actually acess this column?

Comment: What type of data is in the column? You using the getString to read it, but it there's actually a number in there, this might not work, depending on your database driver.

Comment: @Ractoc  The field is a string field and the actual data in the field is literally `'Ff'`

Comment: Could you tell us which database you're using (my bet is on MySQL), what the complete stack trace is, and how your table is defined? That said, the workaround is obvious: use `rs.getString(i)`.

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Javadoc definition for ResultSet.getString method

> getString
>
> String getString(String columnLabel) throws SQLException
>
> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as a String in the Java programming language.

**Parameters:**

> columnLabel - the label for the column specified with the **SQL AS clause**. **If the SQL AS clause was not specified**, then the label is the name of the column

**Returns:**
the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is null

**Throws:**

> SQLException - if the columnLabel is not valid; if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set

So you may need to see on your SQL request and be sure that you did not use a SQL AS clause otherwise you use the supplied label instead of the column name

Comment: It turned out to be an alias.  I removed it and procedure runs w/o exception.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your company_code attribute is not a string try using a different method for get the column value.

If company_code is an integer type try this:

```
rs.getInt(column_name)
```

Or you  can you getObject method

```
rs.getObject(column_name)
```